# Is there a script that allows you to do a easy selection of specific faces in terms of shape and size?

Tags: scripting

I am relatively new to Blender and I came face to this problem, is there a way (script) for me to do a selection of specific faces in terms of size and shape in a project with several objects that are similar?

I am currently working on a project that has a lot of building and houses and I would like to know if its possible to select specific faces of these houses that are both quads and a specific size in order to implement for example some decorations.

I have tried some scripting but I am at a lost in the selection part.

Thanks so much in advance for your time in reading this and I wish you all a good day.

Jacob

Comment: pls show us your script so we know where we can help you specifically. As you have written it now it might look like you are just looking for someone to do your work. thx.

Comment: In Face select mode, with Shift G (or Select > Select Similar) you can select faces that have the same area or perimeter, etc